# Binary Search Tree can't compare node to null

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to do method that removes node from Binary search tree and I know my programming logic is right but I can't compare my focus node to the node's parents left child. It has to be sometimes null and I should be able to compare it to object right?

Here is my code:

```
public void deleteNode(Node node) {           
    if (node.getParent().left().root == node) {
        node.getParent().setLeft(null);
    } else {
        node.getParent().setRight(null);
    }
}
```

So the line that is causing problems is:

```
node.getParent().left().root == node
```

Because it gives `Nullpointerexception`. But I know that it should be null, that is the point of the code. I wouldn't want to use try catch with `NullPointerException` either because it is bad.

Comment: first check if there is a left child.. node.getParent()!=null && node.getParent().left()!=null

Comment: This isn't a correct solution for deleting from a BST. I'm assuming you know about recursion?

Comment: @DavieBrown Before calling deleteNode function I have recursively searched the right node then search function puts the node to deleteNode function's parameter. Isnt that right way to do it?

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake. That sounds correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok let's analyze your code since you're not reading the comments:

```
public void deleteNode(Node node) {           
    if (node.getParent().left().root == node) {//this is where you get NullPointerException
        node.getParent().setLeft(null);
    } else {
        node.getParent().setRight(null);
    }
}
```

Why are you getting a NullPointerException on the line `if (node.getParent().left().root == node)` ?

You get it because: `node.getParent()` is equal to `null` **OR** `node.getParent().left()` is equal to `null`. You cannot call a method on `null`. 
Suppose node.getParent() is `null` in that case you are calling `null.left()`. 
**Does it makes sense?**

Change your code in order to avoid a `NullPointerException`:

```
    if (node.getParent() != null) {
        if (node.getParent().left() != null && node.getParent().left().root == node)
            node.getParent().setLeft(null);
        else
            node.getParent().setRight(null);
    }
```

**Note:** @user3790046 I didn't change your logic. I don't know whether it makes sense or not, I just added the relative checks to avoid the NullPointerException.

Comment: @user3790046 I'm glad it helped you. The important thing is to always try to solve it yourself but if you get stuck this is the right place to come.